# Pandas CSV averaging and sorting

Tags: python, database, sorting, csv, pandas

For my final Computing Python task I am being asked to program a database program in Python that will allow me to access three class databases each containing the three scores of a pupil who have sat a arithmetic quiz. There are three ways in which the code must be sorted; in alphabetical order using the first name, as an average by adding all of the three scores and dividing it by three to find the lone value, and sorting the scores from their highest score to lowest score.
So assume if the following is one of the CSV files:

```
name1       name2 score1 score2 score3
Atticus     Finch 9      8      10
Jem         Finch 5      7      6
Jean Louise Finch 3      2      4
```

If the end user wants it sorted in alphabetical order this is what it should look like on the Python IDLE GUI:

```
Atticus     Finch 9      8      10
Jean Louise Finch 3      2      4
Jem Finch   Finch 5      7      6
```

If the end user wants it sorted as an average this is what it should look like:

```
Atticus     Finch 9
Jem         Finch 6
Jean Louise Finch 3
```

And if the end user wants it sorted from highest to lowest this is what it should look like:

```
Atticus     Finch 10     9      8
Jem         Finch 7      6      5
Jean Louise Finch 4      3      2
```

Right now this is what my code currently looks like:

```
print("Welcome to the Database sorter. The system works based on the following functions. Choose your class by inputting a letter, and choose the method of sorting the data by inputing a number afterwards. A is for Class A, B is for Class B and C is the Class C.1 is for soritng the data as an average, 2 is for sorting the data in alphabetical order and 3 is for sorting the data from highest to lowest.")

classanddatasorter =''
while classanddatasorter not in ["A1","A2","A3","B1","B2","B3","C1","C2","C3"]:
classanddatasorter = input("You have the following nine options. Input A1 to sort the results of Class A as an average. Input A2 to sort the results of Class A in alphabetical order. Input A3 to sort the results of Class A from highest to lowest. Input B1 to sort the results of Class B as an average. Input B2 to sort the results of Class B in alphabetical order. Input B3 to sort the results of Class B from highest to lowest. Input C1 to sort the results of Class C as an average. Input C2 to sort the results of Class C in alphabetical order. Input C3 to sort the results of Class C from highest to lowest. ")
if classanddatasorter == "A1":
 df = pd.read_csv('classa.csv')
 df[["score1", "score2","score3"]].mean(axis=1)

elif classanddatasorter == "A2":
 df = pd.read_csv('classa.csv')
 saved_column = df.column_name
 name = df.name
 name.sort 

elif classanddatasorter == "A3":
 df = pd.read_csv('classa.csv')
 df.sort[('score1','score2','score3'], ascending=False) 

elif classanddatasorter == "B1":
 df = pd.read_csv('classb.csv')
 df[["score1", "score2","score3"]].mean(axis=1)  

elif classanddatasorter == "B2":
 df = pd.read_csv('classb.csv')
 saved_column = df.column_name
 name = df.name

elif classanddatasorter == "B3":
 df = pd.read_csv('classb.csv')
 df.sort[('score1','score2','score3'], ascending=False)

elif classanddatasorter == "C1":
 df = pd.read_csv('classc.csv')
 df[["score1", "score2","score3"]].mean(axis=1)

elif classanddatasorter == "C2":
 bamboo = pd.read_csv('classc.csv')
 saved_column = df.column_name
 name = df.name
 name.sort 

elif classanddatasorter == "C3":
 df = pd.read_csv('classc.csv')
 df.sort[('score1','score2','score3'], ascending=False)
```

I'm getting the following errors so far:

Trying to sort the code as an average:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MVMCJK\Downloads\Python code\Seperate independent draft of Task 3 (not intergated with Task 1 and 2) draft 3.py", line 70, in <module>
df[["score1", "score2","score3"]].mean(axis=1)
  File "C:\Users\MVMCJK\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1791, in __getitem__
return self._getitem_array(key)
  File "C:\Users\MVMCJK\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1835, in _getitem_array
indexer = self.ix._convert_to_indexer(key, axis=1)
  File "C:\Users\MVMCJK\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1112, in _convert_to_indexer
raise KeyError('%s not in index' % objarr[mask])
KeyError: "['score1' 'score2' 'score3'] not in index"
```

Trying to sort the code in alphabetical order:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MVMCJK\Downloads\Python code\Seperate independent draft of Task 3 (not intergated with Task 1 and 2) draft 3.py", line 74, in <module>
saved_column = df.column_name
  File "C:\Users\MVMCJK\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2150, in __getattr__
(type(self).__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'column_name'
```

The last part doesn't even work remotely: It refuses to run by default due to invalid syntax, and I have to eliminate it to get the program working, which doesn't even give a response when I input A3.
I have tried Googling for the KeyError and AttributeError but I cannot find anything that correlates with my problems and enables me to find a further fix. Does anyone know what is funny with my program? Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: Updated still not functioning code:

```
print("Welcome to the Database sorter. The system works based on the following functions. Choose your class by inputting a letter, and choose the method of sorting the data by inputing a number afterwards. A is for Class A, B is for Class B and C is the Class C.1 is for soritng the data as an average, 2 is for sorting the data in alphabetical order and 3 is for sorting the data from highest to lowest.")
classanddatasorter =''
while classanddatasorter not in ["A1","A2","A3","B1","B2","B3","C1","C2","C3"]:
classanddatasorter = input("You have the following nine options. Input A1 to sort the results of Class A as an average. Input A2 to sort the results of Class A in alphabetical order. Input A3 to sort the results of Class A from highest to lowest. Input B1 to sort the results of Class B as an average. Input B2 to sort the results of Class B in alphabetical order. Input B3 to sort the results of Class B from highest to lowest. Input C1 to sort the results of Class C as an average. Input C2 to sort the results of Class C in alphabetical order. Input C3 to sort the results of Class C from highest to lowest. ")
if classanddatasorter == "A1":
 df = pd.read_csv('classa.csv')
 df['average'] = df[['score1', 'score2', 'score3']].mean(axis=1)

elif classanddatasorter == "A2":
 df = pd.read_csv('classa.csv', index_col='name1')
 saved_column = df.column_name
 name = df.name
 name.sort 

elif classanddatasorter == "A3":
 df = pd.read_csv('classa.csv')
 scores = df[['score1', 'score2', 'score3']].values
 scores.sort(axis=1)


elif classanddatasorter == "B1":
 df = pd.read_csv('classb.csv')
 df['average'] = df[["score1", "score2","score3"]].mean(axis=1)


elif classanddatasorter == "B2":
 df = pd.read_csv('classb.csv',index_col='name1')
 saved_column = df.column_name
 name = df.name

elif classanddatasorter == "B3":
 df = pd.read_csv('classb.csv')
 scores = df[['score1', 'score2', 'score3']].values
 scores.sort(axis=1)

elif classanddatasorter == "C1":
 df = pd.read_csv('classc.csv')
 df['average'] = df[["score1", "score2","score3"]].mean(axis=1)

elif classanddatasorter == "C2":
 df = pd.read_csv('classc.csv',index_col='name1')
 saved_column = df.column_name
 name = df.name
 df = name.sort 

elif classanddatasorter == "C3":
 df = pd.read_csv('classc.csv')
 scores = df[['score1', 'score2', 'score3']].values
 scores.sort(axis=1)
```

EDIT 2: Updated with some of bakkal's code samples.

```
print("Welcome to the Database sorter. The system works based on the following functions. Choose your class by inputting a letter, and choose the method of sorting the data by inputing a number afterwards. A is for Class A, B is for Class B and C is the Class C.1 is for soritng the data as an average, 2 is for sorting the data in alphabetical order and 3 is for sorting the data from highest to lowest.")
classanddatasorter =''
while classanddatasorter not in ["A1","A2","A3","B1","B2","B3","C1","C2","C3"]:
 classanddatasorter = input("You have the following nine options. Input A1 to sort the results of Class A as an average. Input A2 to sort the results of Class A in alphabetical order. Input A3 to sort the results of Class A from highest to lowest. Input B1 to sort the results of Class B as an average. Input B2 to sort the results of Class B in alphabetical order. Input B3 to sort the results of Class B from highest to lowest. Input C1 to sort the results of Class C as an average. Input C2 to sort the results of Class C in alphabetical order. Input C3 to sort the results of Class C from highest to lowest. ")

if classanddatasorter == "A1":
 df = pd.read_csv('classa.csv')
 print('Sorted by name1')
 df.sort('name1')
 print(df)
elif classanddatasorter == "A2":
 df = pd.read_csv('classa.csv')
 print('Sorted by average column')
 df['average'] = df[['score1', 'score2', 'score3']].mean(axis=1)
 print(df)
 print(df[['name1', 'name2', 'average']].sort('average'))
elif classanddatasorter == "A3":
 df = pd.read_csv('classa.csv')
 print('Sorted scores')
 scores = df[['score1', 'score2', 'score3']].values
 scores.sort(axis=1)

 for i in xrange(0, scores.shape[1]):
     column_name = 'rank{}'.format(i)
     df[column_name] = scores[:, i]

print(df[['name1', 'name2', 'rank2', 'rank1', 'rank0']])
elif classanddatasorter == "B1":
 df = pd.read_csv('classb.csv')
 print('Sorted by name1')
 df.sort('name1')
 print(df)
elif classanddatasorter == "B2":
 df = pd.read_csv('classb.csv')
 print('Sorted by average column')
 df['average'] = df[['score1', 'score2', 'score3']].mean(axis=1)
 print(df)
 print(df[['name1', 'name2', 'average']].sort('average'))
elif classanddatasorter == "B3":
 df = pd.read_csv('classb.csv')
 print('Sorted scores')
 scores = df[['score1', 'score2', 'score3']].values
 scores.sort(axis=1)

for i in xrange(0, scores.shape[1]):
    column_name = 'rank{}'.format(i)
    df[column_name] = scores[:, i]

print(df[['name1', 'name2', 'rank2', 'rank1', 'rank0']])
elif classanddatasorter == "C1":
 df = pd.read_csv('classc.csv')
 print('Sorted by name1')
 df.sort('name1')
 print(df)
elif classanddatasorter == "C2":
 df = pd.read_csv('classc.csv')
 print('Sorted by average column')
 df['average'] = df[['score1', 'score2', 'score3']].mean(axis=1)
 print(df)
 print(df[['name1', 'name2', 'average']].sort('average'))
elif classanddatasorter == "C3":
 df = pd.read_csv('classc.csv')
 print('Sorted scores')
 scores = df[['score1', 'score2', 'score3']].values
 scores.sort(axis=1)

 for i in xrange(0, scores.shape[1]):
     column_name = 'rank{}'.format(i)
     df[column_name] = scores[:, i]

print(df[['name1', 'name2', 'rank2', 'rank1', 'rank0']])
```

Answer (score 0):

### Parsing and Exploring

Assuming we have a CSV file like this (look out for spaces after commas, and have it be commas separated, otherwise you will need to use CSV options to your specific format)

**scores.csv**

```
name1,name2,score1,score2,score3
Atticus,Finch,9,8,10
Jem,Finch,5,7,6
Jean Louise,Finch,3,2,4
```

We read the CSV file

```
df = pd.read_csv('scores.csv')
```

Now `df` is:

```
         name1  name2  score1  score2  score3
0      Atticus  Finch       9       8      10
1          Jem  Finch       5       7       6
2  Jean Louise  Finch       3       2       4
```

and `df.columns` is:

```
Index([u'name1', u'name2', u'score1', u'score2', u'score3'], dtype='object')
```

As you can see `df` has `columns` but no `column_name` attribute, hence your error below

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'column_name'

### Sorting

Now let's do an alphabetic sort

```
df.sort('name1')
```

Result is:

```
         name1  name2  score1  score2  score3
0      Atticus  Finch       9       8      10
2  Jean Louise  Finch       3       2       4
1          Jem  Finch       5       7       6
```

You wanted the average, let's add a column

```
df['average'] = df[['score1', 'score2', 'score3']].mean(axis=1)
```

`df` now has a new column you can sort by!

```
         name1  name2  score1  score2  score3  average
0      Atticus  Finch       9       8      10        9
1          Jem  Finch       5       7       6        6
2  Jean Louise  Finch       3       2       4        3
```

If you just want to see the `average` column

```
df[['name1', 'name2', 'average']].sort('average')


         name1  name2  average
0      Atticus  Finch        9
1          Jem  Finch        6
2  Jean Louise  Finch        3
```

The last score sort you want is sort of tricky given that the data is not tidy/normalized, but here's an attempt

```
scores = df[['score1', 'score2', 'score3']].values
```

`scores` now looks like this

```
array([[ 9,  8, 10],
       [ 5,  7,  6],
       [ 3,  2,  4]])
```

We sort the `scores` array

```
scores.sort(axis=1)

array([[ 8,  9, 10],
       [ 5,  6,  7],
       [ 2,  3,  4]])
```

These are the sorted scores you want, so let's put them into our `df`, we'll have to do this for each score column, so we can use `scores.shape[1]` which is number of columns in that 2D array

```
for i in xrange(0, scores.shape[1]):
    column_name = 'rank{}'.format(i)
    df[column_name] = scores[:, i]
```

Now our `df` looks like this

```
         name1  name2  score1  score2  score3  rank0  rank1  rank2
0      Atticus  Finch       9       8      10      8      9     10
1          Jem  Finch       5       7       6      5      6      7
2  Jean Louise  Finch       3       2       4      2      3      4
```

And to get the display you wanted

```
df[['name1', 'name2', 'rank2', 'rank1', 'rank0']]


         name1  name2  rank2  rank1  rank0
0      Atticus  Finch     10      9      8
1          Jem  Finch      7      6      5
2  Jean Louise  Finch      4      3      2
```

### Tidy Data

You can read more about tidying data by reading [this PDF paper](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v59/i10/paper)

Basically a lot of manipulations will be easier if e.g. your data should look like this

```
name, test, score
bob, 1, 10
bob, 2, 9
```

instead of

```
name, score1, score2
bob, 10, 9
```

### Python script

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('scores.csv')

print('Original Data')
print(df)

print('Sorted by name1')
df.sort('name1')
print(df)

print('Sorted by average column')
df['average'] = df[['score1', 'score2', 'score3']].mean(axis=1)
print(df)
print(df[['name1', 'name2', 'average']].sort('average'))

print('Sorted scores')
scores = df[['score1', 'score2', 'score3']].values
scores.sort(axis=1)

for i in xrange(0, scores.shape[1]):
    column_name = 'rank{}'.format(i)
    df[column_name] = scores[:, i]

print(df[['name1', 'name2', 'rank2', 'rank1', 'rank0']])
```

Instead of `print()` you can also save the resulting dataframes to another `.csv` too, with e.g. `.to_csv('score_sorted_avg.csv')`

Comment: I apologize but I'm struggling to really utilize your solution to make my code work. I haven't copied it word for word (which is probably the reason why it's failing to function), but I don't really understand the use of In[x] and Out[x], and so I... did something? I tried using some of your examples in a redraft but it's still not "working." Could you elaborate on the use of In[x] and Out[x] as well as some explanation on using your techniques? I'll post my updated code in my original post to explain. I apologize for my relative ignorance - first time using pandas. @bakkal

Comment: Oh, ignore the In/Out things, they are from an interactive prompt called IPython, In being what I type in, Out being the output I get from execution

Comment: @TheGeezer There you go I pieced it all together for you to run as a python script, the assumed `scores.csv` file is at the top of my answer

Comment: @TheGeezer Do you still have problems running that script?

Comment: Apologies for the delay - bit busy with other work trying to patch things up. In regards to the program I again slightly tweaked the layout of it.  Something wonky is going on but I'm not sure if it's bad indentation or something really wonky due to IDLE simply outputting "invalid syntax," when I try to run it. I'll post the updated updated code in the desc again. I really appreciate your help @bakkal, you've been a absolute lifesaver.

Comment: @TheGeezer No problem! If IDLE is giving you trouble, try copying my script at the bottom, and saving it as a `scores.py` and then run it `python scores.py` while having `scores.csv` in the same folder, that should run and produce similar output as the one I pasted. Have fun!